# Error: 3706 Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed

Tags: excel, connection-string, oledb, oledbconnection

I recently upgraded to Office 2019 from Office 2007 and I am facing issue with the connection string.

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strExcelPath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;"";"
```

This used to work before and now I am getting `"Error: 3706 . Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed"` Can someone help me in understanding why I am getting this error.

Other than excel upgrade, nothing else is changed.

Comment: If you look in the registry under `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\` do you have any entries starting with *Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB* ?

Comment: Yes, I have Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0

Comment: I changed the OLEDB.16.0 in connection string and it worked. Just one doubt, what should be done in order for the connection string to work? Because, it was working fine previously with 12.0 itself. What could have gone wrong during the excel upgrade?

Comment: I don't know - I've never seen the version 12 entry get removed by an upgrade.